# Binding an RxSwift Observable to an array

Tags: reactive-programming, observable, rx-swift

Trying out RxSwift and trying to convert my network calls. I can't seem to display my data in the view because im not sure how I convert my observable to something my views can use. Here's an example of my request:

```
class SomeService {

    let provider = Provider()
    func getData() -> Observable<[Object]?> { // Returns json
        return provider
            .request(.getSomething())
            .debug()
            .mapArrayOptional(type: Object.self) 
            // Using Moya_Modelmapper map each item in the array
    }

}
```

In my view controller I get the data:

```
 let data = Service.getData()
 print(data) ... <Swift.Optional<Swift.Array<MyApp.Item>>>
```

I have tried to subscribe to the response to the sequence but I don't know how I actually convert it to something like an array I can use in my view.

**UPDATE:** With answer implemented:

```
    func itemsObserver() {
        print("Time to print step 1") // This gets printed
        data
        .filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
        .subscribe(
            onNext: { objects in
                print(objects as Any) 
                print("Step 2") // This does not get executed at all
            },
            onCompleted:{ objects in
                print(objects as Any) // This is ()
                print("Complete") // This gets printed
            }
            ).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }
    itemsObserver()
```

**Console output:**

```
 Time to print step 1
 Service.swift:21 (getData()) -> subscribed
 Service.swift:21 (getData()) -> Event next(Status Code: 200, Data Length: 141)
 Service.swift:21 (getData()) -> Event completed
 Service.swift:21 (getData()) -> isDisposed
 ()
 Complete
```

Comment: Your `getData` method seems infinitely recursive. I assume that isn't intentional. Maybe you could post some more info about the code? For example, the interface of this `Provider` class...

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion the method in the provider is called something else in reality, so getData has a method called getSomething. My bad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

If your `onNext` block isn't getting called at all, it's because `data` never produced anything. Either your producer isn't producing any objects or `mapArrayOptional` is not transforming them.

The `onCompleted` block doesn't accept any arguments so the `objects` var you have in it is meaningless/Void.

---

Try this:

```
let data = service.getData()
data
    .filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! } // this removes the optionality of the result.
    .subscribe(onNext: { objects in
        // in here `objects` will be an array of the objects that came through.
}).disposed(by: bag)
```

Comment: Not sure what's going on here: 

`service.swift:21 (getData()) -> subscribed
service.swift:21 (getData()) -> Event next(Status Code: 200, Data Length: 141)
service.swift:21 (getData()) -> Event completed
service.swift:21 (getData()) -> isDisposed

                onNext: { objects in
                    print(objects as Any) // nil
                    print("Step 2") // Step 2"
                },
                onCompleted:{ objects in
                    print(objects as Any) // ()
                    print("Complete") // Complete
                }`

Comment: So my request shows my in the subscription that onNext is returning data but when I'm trying to print out objects in the onNext method it's nil?

Comment: The code in my answer won't allow `objects` to be nil. I think you need to add more code to your question.

Comment: I added your code snippet in the question and comments on what happens. My on next function never fires. @Daniel-T

Comment: I think you're right on the fact that the mapArrayOptional is not transforming my content. Which is a completely different question all together. But thank you so much for your help. Will mark this as answered.